wkhtmltopdf with pdfkit: PDF blank when referencing local CSS file
I'm experiencing an issue when using wkhtmltopdf with pdfkit to convert an HTML file to PDF. The HTML file references a local CSS file for styling. When I remove the CSS reference, the PDF is generated correctly with all the HTML content. However, when I include the CSS file reference, the resulting PDF is blank.
Here's a summary of the setup:

HTML file references a local CSS file for styling.
Using pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf to convert the HTML to PDF.
Without the CSS file, the PDF content is correctly generated.
With the CSS file, the PDF is blank.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried the following without success:

Using absolute paths for the CSS file.
Adding the --enable-local-file-access option.
Verifying the CSS file path and file permissions.


Can you show the URLs that you're using to the CSS file? Are you using file:// or just the bare path?

The reason we ask for YOUR CODE is that in most cases, out of the box components will usually work per their own syntax. Thus for WkHTMLtoPDF alone, it needs something like this. With  --enable-local-file-access which you said you applied.

However your using with PDFkit and that imposes other requirements such as setting paths and other environmental configurations.

If the source HTML has relative URLs (/images/cat.png) or protocols (//example.com/site.css) that need to be resolved, you can pass :root_url and :protocol options to PDFKit:

PDFKit.new(html, root_url: 'http:/example.com/').to_file
# or:
PDFKit.new(html, protocol: 'https').to_file

more configuration options for windows users can be found at https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration
